# Okular TypeWriter annomation with explicit Chinese words makes the file size super huge & Revocation doesn't restore file size

Tags: pdf, annotations, okular

### Q1: Is there any solution to avoid such huge size change?

As also discussed in [this Linux forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=374808), when I use okular to add explicit text annomations, the file size will become huge, this seems to be related with fonts, e.g. explicit notes with Chinese words cause the file size increase 20M while English words 888K per notes.

### Q2: How to restore the size after removing annomations

Another problem is removing the notes doesn't restore the file size back, any solutions or reasons?

### Appendix

To explaine the problem in detail, for example, let me use [this pdf file](https://www.science.org/doi/epdf/10.1126/scirobotics.aaz6451) (original file size: 7.3M or 7384K) to test the behavior of the annomications.

1. every highlight/underline/squiggle/strike out/freehand increases 4K

- after highlight/underline/squiggle/strike out the title: 7.3M (7388K)
- revoke the highlight/underline/squiggle/strike out: 7.3M (7388K),  didn't release the size!

2. TypeWriter/Inline Note with **one English word** increases 888K

- after typewriter/inline note with a word 'Hallelujah': 8.1M (8272)
- revoke the typewriter/inline content: 8.1M (8272K), didn't release the size!

3. TypeWriter/Inline Note with **one Chinese phrase** increases **20.7M**

- after typewriter/inline note with a word '哈利路亞': 28M
- revoke the typewriter/inline content: 28M, didn't release the size!
- also tested with other pdf files written in Chinese, still increased **20M**

4. popup note with **few English words** increases 4K, revoke doesn't release size.
5. popup note with **one Chinese phrase** increases 4k, revoke doesn't release size, but huge improvement than explicit notes.

### Update

- My OS is WSL2: Ubuntu 23.04
- Okular 22.12.3
- I installed the latest `poppler-23.06.0` and `poppler-data-0.4.12` from `Github`, and I checked the version of one of `poppler-untils`, i.e. `pdfimages`, means it's already 23.06.0

Answer (score 1):

Check out the version of `poppler` package.
It was resolved for me after updating from `23.05.0-1` to `23.06.0-1`.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469829

Comment: Thank you very much! Firstly I don't know how to check my poppler version, however I managed to dowload the latest version and followed the installation instructions on Github. Secondly, I still don't see my problem solved. Confused.